# How to make EitherT[Future, String, Int] from Future[Either[String, Int]] with cats?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have this code:

```
  type Response[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]

  val powerLevels = Map(
    "Jazz" -> 6,
    "Bumblebee" -> 8,
    "Hot Rod" -> 10
  )
  def getPowerLevel(autobot: String): Response[Int] = {

    val result = Future {
      powerLevels.get(autobot) {
        case Some(number) => Right(number)
        case None         => Left(s"Can't get connect to $autobot")
      }
    }

  }
```

I can't understand how I can convert result of calculation in function `getPowerLevel` (`Future[Either[String, Int]]`) to (Writer correctly to `Response[Int]` type. I'd like to do calling `powerLevels.get(autobot)` in `Future`.

Comment: You are missing a `match` after the `get(autobot)` and to create an **EitherT** you only need to pass `result` to the _constructor_. E.g. `new EitherT(result)`.

Comment: Link to the docs that describe how to do this: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html#from-eithera-b-or-feithera-b-to-eithertf-a-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Luis pointed out, all you need to use is `EitherT.apply`:

```scala
import cats.data.EitherT
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import cats.implicits._

  type Response[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]

  val powerLevels = Map(
    "Jazz" -> 6,
    "Bumblebee" -> 8,
    "Hot Rod" -> 10
  )

  def getPowerLevel(autobot: String): Response[Int] = {

      val result = Future {
        powerLevels.get(autobot) match {
          case Some(number) => Right(number)
          case None         => Left(s"Can't get connect to $autobot")
        }
      }
     EitherT(result)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Monad transformers take stackable monads to return a composable monad.** For example, in this case `EitherT[Future, String, A]` will take `Future[Either[String, A]]` to return a monad that is composable.

Although other solutions aptly satisfy this requirement, we can make use of `cond` API from `Either` to write it more succinctly like so:

```
  def getPowerLevel(autobot: String): Response[Int] = {
    val powerLevel = powerLevels.get(autobot)
    EitherT(Future(Either.cond(powerLevel.isDefined, powerLevel.get, s"$autobot unreachable")))
  }
```